# Add +1 to each item in a comma-separated string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe structured as follows:

```
|    ID    |     Start    |    Stop    |
________________________________________
|     1    |    1,2,3,4   |  5,6,7,7   |
|     2    |    100,101   |  200,201   |
```

For each row in the dataframe, I'd like to add 1 to each value in the Start column. The dtype for the Start column is 'object'.

Desired output looks like this:

```
|    ID    |     Start    |    Stop    |
________________________________________
|     1    |    2,3,4,5   |  5,6,7,7   |
|     2    |    101,102   |  200,201   |
```

I've tried the following (and many versions of the following), but get an error stating ,TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects,:

```
 df['test'] = [str(x + 1) for x in df['Start']]
```

I tried casting the column as an int, but got 'Invalid literal for long() with base 10: '101,102':

```
df['test'] = [int(x) + 1 for x in df['start'].astype(int)]
```

I tried converting the field to a list using str.split(), then casting each item as an integer:

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try `df['test'] = [str(int(x) + 1) for x in df['Start']]`?

Comment: I did, and it throws the same 'Invalid literal for long() with base 10:...' error.

Comment: What was the error when you used both `split` and `int`? The full error, with no ellipsis.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/selasady/impala_scripts/testing.py", line 21, in <module>
    df['test'] = [str(int(x) + 1) for x in df['start']]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '101,102,'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df['Start']` is the whole series, so you have to iterate that and *then* split:

```
new_series = []
for x in df['Start']:
    value_list = []
    for y in x.rstrip(',').split(','):
        value_list.append(str(int(y) + 1))
    new_series.append(','.join(value_list))
df['test'] = new_series
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still get this error: 

value_list.append(str(int(y) + 1))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Do you have data that you didn't include in your example? That could be a dangling comma causing the `''`.

Comment: Thanks so much Paulo! There were trailing commas. I ran rstrip(',') on the column, then ran your function and it works perfectly. Will you please add this step to your function so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

By telling you that you cannot concatenate string and int objects you know that x must be a string. You can solve this by casting x to an int before adding 1 to it. So `str(x+1)` becomes `str(int(x)+1)`.

```
df['test'] = [str(int(x) + 1) for x in df['Start']]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, and got, "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'." So i added 'str.split(',') and got "TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'"

Comment: Without the split(','), I get the "invalid literal for int() with base 10" error. I'm stumped!

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Start' : [ [1 , 2, 3 , 4] , [100 , 101] ] , 'Stop' : [ [5 , 6 , 7 ,7] , [200,201] ] })
df.Start =  df.Start.apply(lambda x : [y + 1 for y in x ])
```